# How to get rows with max date when grouping in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table with prices and dates on product:

```
id
product
price
date
```

I create a new record when price change. And I have a table like this:

```
id product price date
1  1       10    2014-01-01
2  1       20    2014-02-17
3  1        5    2014-03-28
4  2       25    2014-01-05
5  2       12    2014-02-08
6  2       30    2014-03-12
```

I want to get last price for all products. But when I group with "product", I can't get a price from a row with maximum date.

I can use `MAX()`, `MIN()` or `COUNT()` function in request, but I need a result based on other value.

I want something like this in final:

```
product price date
1        5    2014-03-28
2       30    2014-03-12
```

But I don't know how. May be like this:

```sql
SELECT product, {price with max date}, {max date}
FROM table
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alternatively, you can have subquery to get the latest get for every product and join the result on the table itself to get the other columns.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  product, MAX(date) mxdate
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY product
        ) b ON a.product = b.product
                AND a.date = b.mxdate
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff's second solution performs better than this approach.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way is a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT product,
       substring_index(group_concat(price order by date desc), ',', 1) as PriceOnMaxDate
       max(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY product;
```

Another way, that might be more efficient than a `group by` is:

```
select p.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.product = t.product and
                        t2.date > t.date
                 );
```

This says:  "Get me all rows from the table where the same product does not have a larger date."  That is a fancy way of saying "get me the row with the maximum date for each product."

Note that there is a subtle difference:  the second form will return all rows that on the maximum date, if there are duplicates.

Also, for performance an index on `table(product, date)` is recommended.

Comment: Your second approach is way much faster than the other solutions posted here. To fetch 15 rows worth of data with some other joins etc, your approach took 0.328 sec, and others approaches posted here took around 4.2 sec

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery that groups by product and return the maximum date for every product, and join this subquery back to the products table:

```
SELECT
  p.product,
  p.price,
  p.date
FROM
  products p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      product,
      MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM
      products
    GROUP BY
      product) m
  ON p.product = m.product AND p.date = m.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    product,
    price,
    date
FROM
    (SELECT
        product,
        price,
        date
    FROM table_name ORDER BY date DESC) AS t1
GROUP BY product;
```